# ASPxGridView getting unbound column values on code behind in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I have devExpress ASPxGridView. I have some bound columns (associated with datasource) and some unbound columns. I have 2 unbound columns and I have drop down and a text field.
So i have 5 bound columns and 2 unbound columns. 
I want all these 7 columns values on code behind file. I can get 5 columns that are bounded but i can not get unbound columns values.

Here is grid code :

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="gvList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="IAD"
Width="100%">
<Columns>
<%-- <dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Sr. No." VisibleIndex="0" Width="30px">
    <dataitemtemplate>
        <%#Container.VisibleIndex + 1%>
    </dataitemtemplate>
    <Settings AllowDragDrop="False" />
    <CellStyle VerticalAlign="Top">
    </CellStyle>
</dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn>--%>

<dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Sr. No." FieldName="Row" VisibleIndex="1"  >
    <CellStyle VerticalAlign="Top" >
    </CellStyle>
</dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn>                  


<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Product" FieldName="Product" VisibleIndex="1" >
    <CellStyle VerticalAlign="Top" >
    </CellStyle>
    <Settings FilterMode="DisplayText"  AutoFilterCondition="Contains" SortMode="Value"  />                                        
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>

<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="UIC" FieldName="UIC" VisibleIndex="1" >
    <CellStyle VerticalAlign="Top" >
    </CellStyle>
    <Settings FilterMode="DisplayText"  AutoFilterCondition="Contains" SortMode="Value"  />                                        
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>


<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="USN" FieldName="USN" VisibleIndex="1" >
    <CellStyle VerticalAlign="Top" >
    </CellStyle>
    <Settings FilterMode="DisplayText"  AutoFilterCondition="Contains" SortMode="Value"  />                                        
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>



<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Allocated To" FieldName="AllocatedTo" VisibleIndex="1" >
    <CellStyle VerticalAlign="Top" >
    </CellStyle>
    <Settings FilterMode="DisplayText"  AutoFilterCondition="Contains" SortMode="Value"  />                                        
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>   

<dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Condition">
    <dataitemtemplate>
        <dxe:ASPxComboBox ID="ddCondition" runat="server" EnableClientSideAPI="True"
       SelectedIndex="0" ValueType="System.String">
        <Items>
            <dxe:ListEditItem Text="--Select--" Value="0" />
            <dxe:ListEditItem Text="Working" Value="working" />
            <dxe:ListEditItem Text="Not Working" Value="not-working" />
        </Items>
        <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e){validateCondition(s)}" />
    </dxe:ASPxComboBox>


    </dataitemtemplate>

    <Settings AllowDragDrop="False" />
    <CellStyle VerticalAlign="Middle">
    </CellStyle>
</dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn>

<dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Remarks">
    <dataitemtemplate>
        <dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="remarks" runat="server" EnableClientSideAPI="True" />
    </dataitemtemplate>

    <Settings AllowDragDrop="False" />
    <CellStyle VerticalAlign="Middle">
    </CellStyle>
</dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn>


<dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn Caption="Send" ShowSelectCheckbox="True">
</dxwgv:GridViewCommandColumn>

</Columns>
```

I have two unbound columns here, one with drop down id : "ddCondition" and  a textfield : "remarks"

I can get values of all bound columns but i want values of drop down and text field too in loop, here is code behind code :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        ProductStr = gvList.GetRowValues(i, "Product")
        Dim dd As DropDownList = CType(gvList.FindRowTemplateControl(i, "ddCondition"), DropDownList)
        Dim str As String = dd.SelectedValue.ToString
    Next i
```

I am getting NullReferenceException on

> Dim str As String = dd.SelectedValue.ToString

Can any one please guide me how can i get values of drop down and text field.

Here is screen shot of my page :

[image]

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue through following code :

```
Private Sub GetSelectedValues()
        Dim ProductStr As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            ProductStr = gvList.GetRowValues(i, "Product")
            Dim dd As ASPxComboBox = CType(gvList.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, Nothing, "ddCondition"), ASPxComboBox)
            Dim str As String = dd.SelectedItem.Value.ToString
            If str <> "0" Then
                Literal1.Text = str
            End If
        Next i
        BindGridView()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 9
    ProductStr = gvList.GetRowValues(i, "Product")
    DropDownList ddCondition = (DropDownList)gvList.Rows[i].FindControl("ddCondition");
    string Condition = ddCondition.SelectedValue.ToString();
Next i
```

Sorry, the two lines I have added are in C# - my VB is way too rusty these days.